# Regex - group name equals up until the next hyphen if present, if not go to the end

Tags: regex

I am using Regex to categorise codes in Omniture.

I need to work out a way where I can get my **Match Group** to go to the next - if present but go to the end if not.

This is an example of a tracking code

> KNC-GUK-FUK-GEN-SUP-MRO-ARALDITE-MRO

My current Regex is (which isn't working as desired)

```
(?i)knc-(.*?)(SUP-)(.*?)(-)(.+)(?= *-|$)
```

So it needs to have **KNC** and **SUP-** and I need to capture the word after the next hypen, in this case **ARALDITE**.

**edit** the codes can be such as **KNC-GUK-FUK-GEN-SUP-MRO-ARALDITE** which is why I have an issue.

Just to clarify, it is the text in the Name in Match Group which I need, not just the match itself.

Is there a way of doing this?

Any help you could offer would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Shani

Answer (score 0):

This matches everything up until the end of ARALDITE:

```
knc-(.+)SUP-[^-]+-[^-]+
```

Where the final `[^-]+` is matching just ARALDITE. I'm afraid I'm not quite sure what the other parts of your attempt are trying to do, or what captures you want to make, but hopefully you can work from this to a final solution.

`[^-]` just matches anything that isn't a hyphen, so of course `[^-]+` matches either until the end of the string or until it encounters a hyphen.

Comment: Hi, That matches fine but I need the group to be such as ADRALITE which it doesn't do. Thanks though

Comment: @user3207116 - I think you might just want `()` around the final `[^-]+` - as I said, it's that part that matches `ARALDITE`, but I wasn't entirely sure what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
KNC-.*?SUP-.*?-(.*?)-
```

Expl.: Make sure "KNC-" is present and followed, at any, point by "SUP-", then skip until next '-' and capture to, not including, the following '-'.

Regards

Comment: Hi, It doesn't always have another hyphen in it so the code can be such as  KNC-GUK-FUK-GEN-SUP-MRO-ARALDITE which it doesn't pull though

Comment: @user3207116: Change it to `KNC-.*?SUP-.*?-(\w*)` and all word characters is captured up to a hyphen or the end of the string.